# Cannot find file when using RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, directory

I am using the following to try and list all the files in a customers directory. It is supposed to replace $customerID in the path with the customers ID from the previous page that is held in GET, but instead I am getting the error message :

> 500 -
>   RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(./customer-files/$customerID,./customer-files/$customerID) [recursivedirectoryiterator.--construct]: The system cannot find the
>   file specified. (code: 2)

```
<?php
$customerID = $_GET['customerID'];
echo '<h1>';
echo $customerID;
echo '</h1>';
?>


<?php
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./customer-files/$customerID')) as $filename)
{
    echo '<p>';
    echo $filename->getFilename();

    echo '</p>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes around your $customerID variable, so you either have to concat, or switch it to double quotes, try this:

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./customer-files/' . $customerID)) as $filename)
```

Comment: Nice. Gotta love the ez fixes. Accept when you can.